# update in PostgreSQL function seems to not work

Tags: postgresql, updates, plpgsql

To learn how to use function in PostgreSQL, we have to do an exercise with the following statement:

We have a table Skieur (skier), Competition and a table Classement (ranking of a skier in a competition).
We have also a fourth table called Penalise (who give us in which competition a skier has cheated).

The goal of the exercise is to write a function (or more if it necessary), to put all the cheaters skier at the last rank of the competition they have cheat, and we have to update the ranking of all the other players.

Here are the different table and insert:

```
CREATE TABLE skieur(
  noSkieur serial,
  nomSkieur VARCHAR,
  idSpecialite INT,
  idStation INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (noSkieur),
  CONSTRAINT fk_skieur_specialite
            FOREIGN KEY (idSpecialite) REFERENCES specialite(idSpecialite),
  CONSTRAINT fk_skieur_station
            FOREIGN KEY (idStation) REFERENCES station(idStation)
);

INSERT INTO skieur VALUES(default,'skieur1',1,1);
INSERT INTO skieur VALUES(default,'skieur2',1,2);
INSERT INTO skieur VALUES(default,'skieur3',2,1);
INSERT INTO skieur VALUES(default,'skieur4',2,3);
INSERT INTO skieur VALUES(default,'skieur5',2,1);
INSERT INTO skieur VALUES(default,'skieur6',3,2);
```

```
CREATE TABLE competition(
  idCompet serial,
  libelleCompet VARCHAR,
  dateCompet DATE,
  idStation INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (idCompet),
  CONSTRAINT fk_competition_station
            FOREIGN KEY (idStation) REFERENCES station(idStation)
);

INSERT INTO competition VALUES(default, 'compet1','2014-09-01',1);
INSERT INTO competition VALUES(default, 'compet2','2014-09-02',1);
INSERT INTO competition VALUES(default, 'compet3','2014-09-03',2);
INSERT INTO competition VALUES(default, 'compet4','2014-09-04',2);
INSERT INTO competition VALUES(default, 'compet5','2014-09-05',2);
INSERT INTO competition VALUES(default, 'compet6','2014-09-06',3);
```

```
CREATE TABLE classement(
  noSkieur INT,
  idCompet INT,
  classement INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(noSkieur, idCompet),
  CONSTRAINT fk_classement_skieur
            FOREIGN KEY (noSkieur) REFERENCES skieur(noSkieur),
  CONSTRAINT fk_classement_competition
            FOREIGN KEY (idCompet) REFERENCES competition(idCompet)
);

INSERT INTO classement VALUES(1,1,1);
INSERT INTO classement VALUES(2,1,2);
INSERT INTO classement VALUES(3,1,3);
INSERT INTO classement VALUES(4,1,4);
INSERT INTO classement VALUES(1,2,1);
INSERT INTO classement VALUES(2,2,2);
INSERT INTO classement VALUES(3,2,3);
INSERT INTO classement VALUES(4,2,4);
INSERT INTO classement VALUES(5,2,5);
INSERT INTO classement VALUES(6,3,1);
INSERT INTO classement VALUES(1,3,2);
```

```
CREATE TABLE penalise(
  noSkieur INT,
  idCompet INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (noSkieur, idCompet),
  CONSTRAINT fk_penalise_competition
            FOREIGN KEY (idCompet) REFERENCES competition(idCompet),
  CONSTRAINT fk_penalise_skieur
            FOREIGN KEY (noSkieur) REFERENCES skieur(noSkieur)
);

INSERT INTO penalise VALUES(1, 1);
```

To write the function, I was thinking to this:

I have a cursor on all cheaters where I iterate on.
I update the ranking of the cheater with the number of players in the competition, to put him last.
Afterwards, I call on other the decrement all the other players ranking between the position of the cheater, until the end or another cheater.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
-- Decrement ranking function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION decrement_ranking(ranking_start integer, id_competition integer)
RETURNS integer
AS $$
DECLARE
  nb_modification integer := 0;
  c CURSOR FOR
    SELECT c.noSkieur, c.classement
    FROM classement AS c
    WHERE c.idCompet = id_competition AND c.classement > ranking_start;
  competiter_ranking integer;  
BEGIN
  FOR c_data IN c
    LOOP
      -- while the competiter is not a cheater
      CONTINUE WHEN c_data.noSkieur NOT IN (SELECT noSkieur FROM penalise WHERE idCompet = id_competition);
      -- get current competiter ranking
      SELECT c.classement INTO competiter_ranking
        FROM classement AS c
        WHERE c.noSkieur = c_data.noSkieur AND idCompet = id_competition;
      -- decrement ranking
      UPDATE classement
        SET classement = competiter_ranking - 1
        WHERE c.noSkieur = c_data.noSkieur AND idCompet = id_competition;
      nb_modification := nb_modification + 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN nb_modification;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Main function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION declasse_penalise()
RETURNS integer
AS $$
DECLARE
  nb_modification integer := 0;
  c CURSOR FOR
    SELECT p.noSkieur, p.idCompet
    FROM penalise AS p;
  no_skieur_pen integer;
  id_compet_cheat integer;
  nb_competiters integer;
  ranking_cheater integer;
BEGIN
  FOR c_data IN c
    LOOP
      no_skieur_pen := c_data.noSkieur;
      id_compet_cheat := c_data.idCompet;

      -- get ranking cheater
      SELECT cl.classement INTO ranking_cheater
        FROM classement AS cl
        WHERE cl.noSkieur = no_skieur_pen AND cl.idCompet = id_compet_cheat;

      -- put cheater in lowest ranking = number of competiters
      SELECT COUNT(sk.noSkieur) INTO nb_competiters
        FROM skieur as sk
        INNER JOIN classement AS cl ON cl.idCompet = id_compet_cheat;

      UPDATE classement
        SET classement = nb_competiters
        WHERE noSkieur = no_skieur_pen AND idCompet = id_compet_cheat;

      -- decrement all other ranking: from cheat player rank to before the next cheater (if there is one)
      nb_modification := nb_modification + decrement_ranking(ranking_cheater, id_compet_cheat);
    END LOOP;
  RETURN nb_modification;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now my problem is that: my code has no compilation errors but it doesn't update as I expected.

Do you have an idea why?

Comment: It would be helpful to show what the data should look like, but I have a few general tips that may be helpful.  First, loops are almost always the wrong way to go in SQL.    Modify sets of data, not individual rows.  Second, instead of updating the rank of all skiers, create a view that puts that skiers in the correct order.  With a view, you wouldn't be modifying the existing data, but could still get the correct rankings.

Comment: I don't understand which data you want me to show. For the loop, it's the way my professors show me in class. And for the idea of create a new view, I have already think of that, but they want me to modify the classement (ranking) records.

Comment: Basically you are missing two data views - that is the data you need to show us (not a database view). Show the results you actually got and what you expected. Also show both sets as text not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what you after, but I couldn't figure out the functions - at least reading through a couple times. But I can tell you are doing way to much work. When working with SQL - regardless of the particular DBMS let SQL do as much of the work as possible. It really is a heavy lifter if you let it be. You indicated you needed a loop. So I'll give you one iterating over cheaters (penalise); but somewhat expanded.

```
create or replace function declasse_penalise()
returns void
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    -- get cheater, competition, cheater's finish place, and number of competitors in competition  
    cheaters cursor for
        select p.noskieur, p.idcompet,c. classement, competors    
          from penalise as p
          join classement  c on (p.noskieur, p.idcompet) = (c.noskieur, c.idcompet) 
          join (select idcompet, max(classement) competors 
                  from classement 
                 group by idcompet
               ) com 
            on p.idcompet = com.idcompet;

  cheater record;

begin

  for cheater in cheaters                                           -- for each cheater
  loop
      update classement
         set classement = case when noskieur = cheater.noskieur     -- cheater, set finish position to last 
                               then cheater.competors 

                               when classement > cheater.classement -- finished after cheater, move position to top
                               then classement - 1

                               else classement                      -- finished before cheater, leave position the same
                         end
        where idcompet = cheater.idcompet;                          -- for particular competition only
  end loop; 

end;
$$; 

-- test 
select * from declasse_penalise2();
select * from classement order by idcompet, classement;
```

I think this satisfies your stated requirement with the data provided - but you should extensively test.  Having just a single row to test with is not sufficient. At a minimum at least 1 test case needs 2 cheaters in the same competition. There may be a issue when that happens as each would have the same finishing position and some position may be skipped.